# How do I return a value of true if the letters 'a' and 'b' are exactly 3 places apart?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a string and outputs a value of true if any of the 'a's in the string are exactly 3 places from the 'b's in the same string. If the 'a's and 'b's are not exactly 3 places from one another than return false.

Examples
Input: "after badly"
Output: false
Input: "Laura sobs"
Output: true

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working. If anyone could take a look and show me where I've gone wrong that would be awesome.

```js
function string(str) {    
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(str[i] === 'a' && str[i+3] === 'b'){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(string('lane borrowed'))
```

Comment: What doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Your loop iterates from 0 to the length of the string. Inside the loop, you are trying to access the item in position i+3, which means - you will try to access out of bounds of the string, and you will get an exception. Change your loop condition

Comment: ^ This is incorrect. Accessing a string at an index out of bounds will just return undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only get the third element based on your code. Since `i+3` get the third element from the `i` which should be two space apart not three space.

```js
function string(str) {    
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(str[i] === 'a' && str[i+4] === 'b'){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(string('lane borrowed'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You're right, it should be i+4 not i+3

Answer (score 1):

Start by thinking through and describing the problem to yourself. Maybe even re-word it. Below is the logic of the code, with some hints on how to implement it.

1. Locate the first "a" in the string. *Hint: Use the `indexOf()` method.*
2. If you are more than 3 characters from the end of the string, check the third position after the position you got in 1. above. *Hint: Use the `substring()` method, e.g. `myString.substring(pos,1)`.*
3. If the character you get in 2. is not "b", and you are not at the end of the string, repeat step 1-3 again. *Hint: Use do ... while()*

Comment: This is definitely the way I will start thinking about challenges. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 3 characters after `a` in `lane borrowed` is a space  . Did you intend to remove whitespace or did you just miscount? Here's a version of your function which removes the whitespace and it does correctly return true.

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

```js
function string(str) {   
    str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(str[i] === 'a' && str[i+3] === 'b'){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(string('lane borrowed'))
console.log(string('lane            borrowed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the letter to be 3 letters apart, you need to add 4 to the first index:

```js
function string(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] === 'a' && str[i+4] === 'b'){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(string('a123b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a good job, but you not remove the blank spaces, so in this case:
'lane borrowed'
str[i] = 'a'
str[i+3] = ' '

only remove the spaces before:

```js
function string(str) {   
  const strWithouBlankSpaces = str.replace(' ', '')

  for (i = 0; i < strWithouBlankSpaces.length; i++) {
    if(strWithouBlankSpaces[i] === 'a' && strWithouBlankSpaces[i+3] === 'b'){
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(string('lane borrowed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the existence of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) one just needs to focus on implementing the test/condition for a valid character sequence. `some` immediately stops iterating the array of character items and returns the `true` boolean value as soon as the condition matches just once ...

```js
function hasCorrectCharacterSequence(char, idx, arr) {
  return (
    (char === 'a')
    && (idx < arr.length - 4)
    && (arr[idx + 1] !== 'b')
    && (arr[idx + 2] !== 'b')
    && (arr[idx + 3] !== 'b')
    && (arr[idx + 4] === 'b')
  );
}

console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "lane borrowed" ?..',
  Array
    .from('lane borrowed')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "laneborrowed" ?..',
  Array
    .from('laneborrowed')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "Laura sobs" ?..',
  Array
    .from('Laura sobs')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "after badly" ?..',
  Array
    .from('after badly')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "arrrbitrary" ?..',
  Array
    .from('arrrbitrary')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "arrbbitrary" ?..',
  Array
    .from('arrbbitrary')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "arbrbitrary" ?..',
  Array
    .from('arbrbitrary')
    .some(hasCorrectCharacterSequence)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit**

A regex like [`/a[^b]{3}b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/c2PJBC/1) does the job as well.

It reads like this ...

- `a` ... match the single character **a**
- `[^b]{3}` ... match exactly **3** characters which are not(`^`) **b**
- `b` ... match the single character **b**

And works like that ...

```js
function hasCorrectCharacterSequence(value) {
  // see...[https://regex101.com/r/c2PJBC/1]

  return (/a[^b]{3}b/g).test(String(value));
}

console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "lane borrowed" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('lane borrowed')
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "laneborrowed" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('laneborrowed')
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "Laura sobs" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('Laura sobs')
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "after badly" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('after badly')
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "arrrbitrary" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('arrrbitrary')
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "arrbbitrary" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('arrbbitrary')
);
console.log(
  'has correct sequence ... "arbrbitrary" ?..',
  hasCorrectCharacterSequence('arbrbitrary')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function string(str) {
  for (i = 0; i < str.length - 3; i++) {
    if (str[i] === 'a' && str[i + 3] === 'b') {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(string('lane borrowed'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).